# Is there any sense in using server side MVC framework when using angularJS routing?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm new to AngularJS(it's great!) and I suddenly realized that I don't need server side MVC framework when using AngularJS routing... Am I right? I mean off course I need some sort of Restful Web API but the use of MVC is redundant no?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Depends on what logic still resides on the server. MVC _can_ be well suited to build RESTful web APIs.

Comment: Can you give an example why will I need server side MVC when using AngularJS routing?